# How to get list of data in Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ceremony Model and it  has  id, date.

I want to get ceremonies which are date<= today.

This is my function in service class.

```
 public virtual IList<Ceremony> GetAllCeremonyByDate(DateTime currentDate)
        {

            var query = from c in _ceremonyRepository.Table
                        where c.ceremony_date >= currentDate
                        select c;
            var countries = query.ToList();
            return countries;

        }
```

This is my controller.

```
   public ActionResult DetailForm()
            {

                Ceremony model = new Ceremony();

                var ceremonyDate = _ceremonyService.GetAllCeremonyByDate(DateTime.Now);
                if (ceremonyDate.Count == 0)
                    return Content("No ceremony can be loaded");

                if (ceremonyDate.Count > 0)
                {

                    foreach (var c in ceremonyDate)
                       // My problem


                }

                return View(model);

            }
```

I don't know how to assign value to model.

Comment: Which kind of value you want to assign?

Comment: ceremony_id and ceremony_date.there are int and dateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is the view expecting?

If it's `IEnumerable<Ceremony>` (or something similar) then your controller just needs to be:

```
public ActionResult DetailForm()
{
    var model = _ceremonyService.GetAllCeremonyByDate(DateTime.Now);

    if (model.Count == 0)
    {
        return Content("No ceremony can be loaded");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

If the view is expecting a `Ceremony` then you need to decide which one to send back.  If you just want the first valid one then you could do something like:

```
public ActionResult DetailForm()
{
    var ceremonies = _ceremonyService.GetAllCeremonyByDate(DateTime.Now);

    if (ceremonies.Count == 0)
    {
        return Content("No ceremony can be loaded");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(ceremonies.First());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're returning a `IList<Ceremony>` your view should accept a model compatible with this type. For example:

**Controller**

```
var ceremonies = _ceremonyService.GetAllCeremonyByDate(DateTime.Now);

if (ceremonies.Count == 0)
{
   return Content("No ceremony can be loaded");
}
else
{
    return View(ceremonies);
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Ceremony>
```

Then you can enumerate your ceremonies in the view like this:

```
@foreach (var ceremony in Model)
{
  ...
}
```

I also think you need to correct your logic. Instead of `>=` use `<=`.

```
var query = from c in _ceremonyRepository.Table
            where c.ceremony_date <= currentDate
            select c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just assign the values to the model instant inside your foreach loop. For example,

```
model.id = c.id;
model.date=c.date;
```